# Deriving property of the Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

It's been awhile since I've done much calculus and I've recently been looking at an identity for the gamma function:

$$\frac {\Gamma(s)}{n^s}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx =\frac 1{n^s} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx$$

I understand how to work back from there and show that they are equal using the substitution $u=nx$, but I'm having trouble seeing how to derive this from:

$$ \frac {\Gamma(s)}{n^s}=\frac 1{n^s} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx$$

I see this used fairly often when deriving the integral form of the Zeta function and I'm just wondering where it comes from.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{s-1}e^{-x}, F(y)= \int_0^y f(x)dx$, $G(y) = F(ny)$ then $G'(x) =n F'(nx)= n f(nx)$ thus $$\int_0^y n f(nx)dx = G(y)-G(0) = F(ny)=\int_0^{ny}f(x)dx$$

Letting $y\to \infty$ you get the change of variable formula $$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=n\int_0^\infty f(nx)dx= n \int_0^\infty n^{s-1}x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$u=nx, du=ndx, du={1\over n}dx$, $x^{s-1}=e^{(s-1)ln(x)}=e^{(s-1)ln({u\over n})}$.

$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx=$

${1\over n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{ln({u\over n})(s-1)}du=$

${1\over n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{(s-1)ln(u)-(s-1)ln(n)}du$

${1\over n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{(s-1)ln(u)}e^{-(s-1)ln(n)}du$

$={1\over n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{s-1}n^{1-s}du$